# Intellij Idea bug with Database

Tags: database, intellij-idea, datasource

I have this exception when connecting to the database through DataSource. 
I use JDBC driver - pointbase, and the database is embedded H2.
Maybe, somebody has some idea why this exception appears? 
Test connection is valid

I added two shotscreen:
[image]
[image]

```
<failed to load>
java.sql.SQLException: JDBC 2.0 Core API Method not yet supported.
    at com.pointbase.dbexcp.dbexcpException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.pointbase.jdbc.jdbcTmpResultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.getObject(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1269)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.getCurrentRow(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1249)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.getObjects(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1229)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
.<failed to load>
java.sql.SQLException: JDBC 2.0 Core API Method not yet supported.
    at com.pointbase.dbexcp.dbexcpException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.pointbase.jdbc.jdbcTmpResultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.getObject(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1269)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.getCurrentRow(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1249)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.getObjects(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1229)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with IntelliJ. 
Your jdbc driver is too old, and doesn't support the required APIs needed for what you're trying to do.

Upgrade your jdbc driver.

Comment: But this driver works properly when I use in Java. How can it be? And in DbSchema program it works properly too. I see all tables in my embedded database.

Comment: @PaulChechegov possibly the IntelliJ database browser uses newer jdbc calls as compared to your own application. Fact remains, it needs functionality your driver version doesn't offer so the only options are to not use the tool or to upgrade the driver. The latter is usually preferred as it also fixes security and performance bugs among other things.